# Blazor: Save uploaded file directly to entity object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor server app and need to enable uploading image files to then save them to a database. The database is being accessed via entity framework core, i.e. the provided entity objects. For uploading I am using the blazor InputFile component.

Usually I would read the entire image as byte array and then save it via the ef core entity object like that:

```
    private async void ImageUpload(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        await e.File.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(ms);
        myEntityObject.ImageData = ms.ToArray();
    }
```

However, the microsoft documentation strongly recommends not using that approach and to never read the whole file to memory: [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server)

> Avoid reading the incoming file stream directly into memory. For example, don't copy file bytes into a MemoryStream or read as a byte array. These approaches can result in performance and security problems, especially in Blazor Server. Instead, consider copying file bytes to an external store, such as a blob or a file on disk. If you need access to a Stream that represents the file's bytes, use IBrowserFile.OpenReadStream.

Is it even possible to not read the whole file as a memory stream? In my understanding, if I want to save the file via the entity object, all the data will always be present in memory. Am I missing something?

Comment: Erk.. I've never seen anything in EF that would allow for streaming directly from a browser to the DB using the C# as a go-between; if EF was capable of reading from an enumerable of bytes and saving to a DB you could have a do at writing an adapter (because I bet it wouldn't do the async read that Blazor would demand) stream that read from the source whenever EF read from it.. But I think this is one of those that might be best where you stream the source bytes to the server's disk and kick off a process to move it to the DB later/in the background.. If you even want the file in the DB (why?)

Comment: *Is it even possible to not read the whole file as a memory stream?* - most definitely; blazor encourages not doing so and a few recent projects I've been streaming huge CSV (multi gigabyte) into a DB, by async reading the file, making entities as I go and tellig EF to save them (bulk extensions) - worked well, but byte[] data is slightly different, because that whole gigabyte might want to be in one column of one row so there isn't a cycle of "create these million items incrementally".

Comment: Not to say it couldn't be done; executing a query where one of the parameters, destined for some binary column, is a stream is supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support but whether you'd convince EF to do it, versus just getting EF to give you a connection you then use directly (seems like less headache)..

Comment: The thing I wonder most about is that even if I can somehow stream the uploaded file to the database, as soon as I access the entity object, the file will be loaded into memory again. So I don't really understand what I'll win when streaming the data to the database instead of just loading it to memory directly.